# How to configure multiple inputs in WSO2 ESB?

Tags: wso2, vfs, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 ESB 4.9 and in the proxy , the transport.vfs.FileURI parameter is used to provide the input path which is a folder in a SFTP server from which the files needs to be processed but i need to configure multiple input paths from different SFTP server in the same proxy. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [scheduled task](https://wso2docs.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/ESB490/pages/624969/Adding+and+Scheduling+Tasks) which triggers an injection to a proxy. This proxy will read in the files from two (or more) input paths using the [file connector](https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/esbconnector/details/345e5336-0d1a-4fb9-93ec-dffee961804b). You have to do the steps to mediate the files manually (search, iterate the found files, read, delete, move etc.) using the [different operations](https://wso2docs.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/ESBCONNECTORS/pages/50861205/Working+with+the+File+Connector) of the file connector.

Example of reading in .txt files from two input paths every 30 seconds:

Scheduled Task:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<task name="Demo_TaskFileConnector_task" class="org.apache.synapse.startup.tasks.MessageInjector" group="synapse.simple.quartz" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <!-- This task will inject a message to a proxy every 30 seconds -->
<trigger interval="30" />
<property name="injectTo" value="proxy" />
<property name="proxyName" value="Demo_TaskFileConnectorMultipleInput_pFromFileConnector" />
<property name="format" value="soap12" />
<property name="message">
    <Trigger xmlns="">
        <GetFiles />
    </Trigger>
</property>
```

Proxy:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="Demo_TaskFileConnectorMultipleInput_pFromFileConnector" transports="jms" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <property name="fileLocation1" value="sftp://UserName:Password@Host1/directory" />
            <property name="fileLocation2" value="sftp://UserName:Password@Host2/directory" />
            <!-- Read in *.txt files from fileLocation1 -->
            <fileconnector.search>
                <source>{$ctx:fileLocation1}</source>
                <filePattern>.*[.](?i)txt$</filePattern>
                <recursiveSearch>false</recursiveSearch>
            </fileconnector.search>
            <!-- Iterate the list of found files in fileLocation1 -->
            <foreach xmlns:ns="http://org.wso2.esbconnectors.FileConnector" xmlns:ns2="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:sec="http://secservice.samples.esb.wso2.org" expression="//ns:file">
                <sequence>
                    <!-- Parse the file name of the found file to use it for reading in -->
                    <property name="fileName" expression="tokenize(//ns:file, '/')[last()]" />
                    <!-- Read in the content of the file -->
                    <fileconnector.read>
                        <source>{$ctx:fileLocation1}</source>
                        <filePattern>{$ctx:fileName}</filePattern>
                        <contentType>text/plain</contentType>
                    </fileconnector.read>
                    <!-- Go on with the mediation of the file. e.g. send to an endpoint -->
                    <!-- Here I simply log the message content -->
                    <log level="full" />
                </sequence>
            </foreach>
            <!-- Read in *.txt files from fileLocation2 -->
            <fileconnector.search>
                <source>{$ctx:fileLocation2}</source>
                <filePattern>.*[.](?i)txt$</filePattern>
                <recursiveSearch>false</recursiveSearch>
            </fileconnector.search>
            <!-- Iterate the list of found files in fileLocation2 -->
            <foreach xmlns:ns="http://org.wso2.esbconnectors.FileConnector" xmlns:ns2="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:sec="http://secservice.samples.esb.wso2.org" expression="//ns:file">
                <sequence>
                    <!-- Parse the file name of the found file to use it for reading in -->
                    <property name="fileName" expression="tokenize(//ns:file, '/')[last()]" />
                    <!-- Read in the content of the file -->
                    <fileconnector.read>
                        <source>{$ctx:fileLocation2}</source>
                        <filePattern>{$ctx:fileName}</filePattern>
                        <contentType>text/plain</contentType>
                    </fileconnector.read>
                    <!-- Go on with the mediation of the file. e.g. send to an endpoint -->
                    <!-- Here I simply log the message content -->
                    <log level="full" />
                </sequence>
            </foreach>
        </inSequence>
    </target>
</proxy>
```